# Sitecore Forms not taking Page design in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7 and I have created a form using Sitecore Forms and attached that form to a page through CMS and for the page I have assigned my Page design to it but it is not showing my header and footer design which is there in my page design.

Below are the steps which i followed to add my form to page:

1.Created a landing page and through presentation details i added my form to the page.
with the placeholders as "mainn" specified in my VS layout.

[image]

2.Same placeholder i have created under my Placeholdersettings

[image]
3.For the landing page i assigned my page design under page design section

[image]

This is the result I am getting: without page design:

[image]

I created one more page and added this rendering through experience editor there I am able to see my page design (header and footer) but on click on form submit it is redirecting to some formid URL and extra added sxa components are also not visible

[image]

Result what I am getting when I click submit button:

**Url which it is redirecting to** "sitecore901.local/formbuilder?fxb.FormItemId=8516cac6-205f-4040-9540-4fd1d787355e&fxb.HtmlPrefix=fxb.513f7c6f-97ac-4f24-8258-6fa184628d02 " and other sxa components added are also not showing up.

[image]

**Workaround :**

Added sitecore form wrapper and inside this i added the MVC form and specified the datasource form is also appearing on the page and its not redirecting and the placeholder for form is changed to this  "/main/container-1/sitecoreFormsWrapper-1"(if i change it to "mainn" i am not able to see my page design so i have kept as it is) .But the sitecore form validations which i have applied for chinese is not working.

I specified the script in my VS under Renderbody() function of form

[image]

The result what i am getting now is:

[image]

I tried specifying that script file under script field of form but still the same issue.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help what needs to be done here?

Comment: Just make sure, you first dragged the Sitecore Form Wrapper rendering on the page, then in this rendering you placed  MVC Form rendering and then select the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're following all the below steps to add a form to a page::

1. Open the Toolbox. In the Forms section, select and drag the **Sitecore Form Wrapper** rendering to the relevant placeholder.

[image]

2. After that, drag an **Mvc Form** rendering to the Sitecore Forms Wrapper.

[image]

3. After dragging the **Mvc Form** onto the page, In the S*elect the Associated Content* dialog box, select the form that you want to display on the page and click OK. The form is now displayed on the page.
4. In the Experience Editor, click **Partial Design** and click **Metadata**. In the SXA Toolbox, in the Forms category, drag and drop the **Forms Scripts** component before the closing /body tag of the page.

[image]

Comment: i followed your steps form is working fine now but validations which were displaying in chinese is now displaying in english i have the validation scripts in my deployed instance folder how can i add it here under form scripts

Comment: have you added reference to that validation script in the Scripts field of Sitecore Forms?

Comment: no actually this is a multilanguage site so i have given reference in the View where renderbody() of the form comes in VS @Raman Gupta

Comment: updated the workarounds please have a look @Raman Gupta